# How to store both integers and strings in a vector?

Tags: c++, vector, types

I need to store elements in a contiguous container like `std::vector`. The problem is the container needs to support insertion or both `int` and `std::string`.

This seems to be difficult to do in C++ since it's a strongly typed language. I thought of doing something like

```
std::vector<std::pair<int, std::string>> container;
```

or

```
struct custom_struct {
  int val;
  std::string;
  bool is_val;    // true if integer and false if string
};
std::vector<custom_struct> container;
```

but neither seems like a great option. The problem with the first one is, idk how to toggle between whether the pair is representing the integer or the string, hence why I came up with the second approach, though the second approach isn't very elegant because I have to repeatedly type check using `is_val`.

Are there other approaches I can consider in C++?

Answer (score 6):

This is what [`std::variant`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) is for:

```
std::vector<std::variant<int, std::string>> container;
```

This is, basically, a typesafe version of `union` from C, C++ too but `std::variant` is type-safe. Correct usage of `std::variant` will force you to implement type-safety correctly and, for example, treat `container[0]` like a `std::string` only if it actually contains a `std::string` (or you'll get a thrown exception as a reward for your mistake). `std::variant` does everything that needs to be done in order to correctly "toggle between whether the [variant] is representing the integer or the string".

The full description and summary of how to use `std::variant` cannot be explained in just one or two paragraphs, so you are referred to your C++ textbook or reference manual for more information. `std::variant` requires C++17, or later.